# How to fix bottom navigation bar below Scroll View in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

I have an activity that has multiple card views inside a nested scroll View. I want to fix the navigation bar at the bottom. But whenever i try to put a bar below a Scrollable content, content covers the bar as well. I have tried wrapping it in a constraint Layout view but that doesn't works either. Here is my layout file.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scroll_view">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/card_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="199dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

                    <TextView

                        android:id="@+id/info_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

                    android:id="@+id/card_view1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

                    <TextView

                        android:id="@+id/info_text1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

                    android:id="@+id/card_view2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

                    <TextView

                        android:id="@+id/info_text2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

                    android:id="@+id/card_view3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

                    <TextView

                        android:id="@+id/info_text3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>


        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/scroll_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to provide constraints to your `NestedScrollView`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `BottomNavigationView` is missing a bottom constraint. Add the following line to it to make it work:

> app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

The underlying problem is that your NestedScrollView has `android:layout_height="match_parent"`, which will make it take up the entire screen, since your ConstraintLayout also has `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

You should generally avoid using `match_parent` for Views in `ConstraintLayouts`.

> Note: You cannot use match_parent for any view in a ConstraintLayout. Instead use "match constraints" (0dp).

See Android Docs [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)

Comment: Thanks. The doc link is broken. I removed the line `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/scroll_view"` and added the bottom constraint you suggested. It is working now.

Comment: @khan I fixed the link.

Answer (score 1):

Your NestedScrollView has  `android:layout_height="match_parent"` I think this is the problem. You should put BottomNavigationView to the bottom and constraint NestedScrollView between parent top and BottomNavigationView

Comment: I'll try it. Because right now even though the bottom is visible. Part of my last card view is hidden below the navigation bar.